# Insert record having field value based on the max value

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a legacy sql that basically inserts record with subquery like this

```sql
INSERT INTO invoice (invno, otherfields ) 
VALUES ( (SELECT Max(invno)+1 AS maxinvno FROM invoices) , othervalues )
```

I'm trying to implement the same in C#'s NHibernate.

My question is:

Is it possible to avoid the SQL/HQL query and use <s>LINQ</s> NHibernate style instead. If possible - how to do that?

for example:

```cs
Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
invoice.invno = ...
session.save
```

update: stroke out the linq reference
update: added snippet with wanted result

Comment: And you can't use an autonumber/database controlled incrementing thing like a sequence?

Comment: The answer is yes. Try to read section 18.6 at this link https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querylinq.html

Comment: @CaiusJard the design is made years ago, not a subject to change

Comment: @Christos, coming right from this article, saw about InsertBulder and so on. Could not figure it out how to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

***** In linq you can try this*****

```
 using (AccountingDbContext dbContext = new AccountingDbContext())
        {
            Transaction objEmp = new Transaction();
            objEmp.VoucherNo = ((from  transction in dbContext.Transactions
                               select transction.Id).Max() + 1).ToString();
            objEmp.TransactionType = "Payment";
            dbContext.Transactions.Add(objEmp);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Bit of dodgy capitalization going on there; can you review?

Comment: @neamulislam Thank you for your answer. I was puzzled by it but after short browsing I realize that this is pure LINQ which means my question is not asked correctly. I'm aiming to chaining methods in the style of NHibernate. I am not sure how to use your snippet in my current environment.